# Crack in ceiling along where it meets exterior wall. Possible causes, should i be worried?

Tags: walls, ceiling, crack

I live in a victorian end terrace. The ceiling where it meets the exterior wall has cracked over time. It is in the same area where there was some subsidence due to cracked drain but repaired some time ago. What could be the causes and should be worried?
[image][image][image]